# undefined_quantity for paypal subscription button

Tags: paypal, subscription, paypal-subscriptions

I want to define a Paypal button with circular payment (once a month), but with custom quantity. For example, if I choose 1 items I will pay 1$ per month, if I choose 2 items I will pay 2$ for month etc..
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from a subscription button that allows the customer to choose between 3 options.

```
    <tbody><tr><td><input name="on0" value="Monthly Autoship" type="hidden"></td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
<option name="item_name" value="1 Pro">1 Pro: $88.84</option>
<option name="item_name" value="2 Pro">2 Pro: $161.29</option>
<option name="item_name" value="3 Pro">3 Pro: $235.87</option>
```

It's just a normal dropdown selection.